# Lenovo Tablet 2 1050L boot failure after attempted root

Tags: unbricking, lenovo

I hope someone can help me. I have a LTE enabled Lenovo Tablet 2 1050L which I attempted to root using the instructions given here ... https://forum.xda-developers.com/thi...let-2-t3251571 ... but I have managed to brick my device. I successfully installed SuperSU but then read that Magisk was better and tried the same procedure with that but it didn't work. Now when the tablet starts up, I get a message which says ... "EFILINUX ERROR [android_image_start_buffer:737] boot image digital signature verification failed : 0000001A" which appears over the initial Lenovo splash screen. I then get to the Android system recovery menu but I can't get the table any further than this. I have tried wiping data / factory resetting but this does not work.

I can boot the tablet into recovery mode using CWM or TWRP but I have no idea what to do now. I guess I shouldn't have messed. I hope someone can help.

Kind regards

Comment: Check for instructions how to restore the original boot image. That is what Magisk replaced after creating a backup. Raw approach: find that image file, then use Fastboot to flash it back. I've never done that, so I cannot give detailed instructions (hence a comment only).

Comment: I've booted back into CWM and TWRP and there are no backups to restore. Does it matter that, following instructions from elsewhere, I wiped the 'data' and 'cache' partitions?

Comment: I didn't tell you there were any backups in the recovery. Magisk creates a backup and places it in its own folder. That's why I wrote "check for instructions". And yes, if you wiped data, that backup is gone. Which leaves you with finding an image of your original boot partition.

Comment: OK - thanks for your help. Can I download a stock ROM and extract boot.img, say from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/ualp03203xlea6c/Lenovo_Yoga_Tablet_2_1050L_USR_S000215_150324.zip)?

Comment: Can't tell, I don't have that device. Btw: If your Lenovo tablet is MTK based, Flashtool (cross-platform) could be helpful as well. I've used that in the past to perform a full backup on another Lenovo tablet *before* I started playing with root etc. A real life saver, as that gave me the chance to restore all partitions after a similar issue. Might not help now (as you didn't use it to backup before), but might come in handy in the future ;) Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the tips - I've flashed [this](http://lenovo-forums.ru/files/file/953-yoga-tablet-2-10-yt2-1050l_usr_s100081_1507241439_ww52_row_l/) ROM and everything seems OK now - do you think I can trust the ROM from 'http://lenovo-forums.ru'?

Comment: No idea. I'd check that with the folks at XDA (in the appropriate forum area).

Answer (score 1):

Install latest ADB drivers
http://download.clockworkmod.com/test/UniversalAdbDriverSetup.msi

install intel android drivers on pc
Intel_Android_Driver_1.10.0
https://androiddatahost.com/wp-content/uploads/Intel_Android_Driver_1.10.0.zip

download restore-kitkat-bios-830-1050-v2.exe
http://lenovo-forums.ru/applications/core/interface/file/attachment.php?id=53522

power off tab, start tab by pressing vol+,vol-,power buttons simulteneously and after a short vibrate, leave power button. Tab should now be in boot mode

start restore-kitkat-bios-830-1050-v2.exe and finish process as per instructions in the app

download android version kitkat 4.4
Lenovo_Yoga_Tablet_2_1050L_USR_S000215_1503241130_WW21_ROW
https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=385035244224392223

install via intel platform flash lite tool
http://www.mediafire.com/file/d4be3zrf189k28n/PhoneFlashToolLite_5.5.2.0_win32.zip

and YOU ARE DONE.. NJOY